# Can’t download Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, download, upgrade

I am trying to install Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan). The traditional way just going to the Mac App Store it s not working ( I tried several times (5times) and the download it’s ALWAYS stopping at 1.79GB, deleting the download, restarting the laptop, running <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to check the hard drive - same result).

After that, I found out that I can download/update with Terminal. I run `softwareupdate -l` but it’s finding other software to be updated but NOT El Capitan. I have a MacBook Pro 13 inch with retina, with Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) running on it.

Comment: Are you low on disk space?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, MacBook Pro 13 (2015) 1.79GB and it stops "OS X El Capitan failed to download," can't seem to find any solution.

Comment: Same problem here. I inherited this old mini running 10.6.8 and cannot get El Capitan to download via the appstore.  One thing I'll add to my situation is that when the app store download fails it logs me out of the app store and I am prompted to log back in again.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same issue. It says "Downloaded" on the Updates screen, but when I click on "Learn Mode" the button for this upgrade says "Download". I click it and nothing happens. The updates screen says I have no update available, even though I am 10.10.5 and have the proper requirements (space, device, etc.)

Comment: Just found I can kick off the installation manually by starting the "Install OS X El Capitan" program under "Applications". Hopefully it works.

Comment: Hi, have you tried getting your date back to 2014? I had big time trouble fixing my friends old macbook air with old thumb drive I had with and old El Capitan. Turns out MacOs has an expiration date and that was in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I could not even see mine to download until I installed all the updates including the Safari update which came out the same day. After that, it worked.

Answer (score -2):

It's not a sure fire way to do it but you can try logging out and back into your Apple account from the Store menu.